# CopyFromRecordset returns only 1 record even though multiple records are present in SQL SSAS cube

Tags: excel, vba, ssas, cube

I want to connect to SQL SSAS Cube and import some records. Problem is that excel is importing only first row. In SQL SSAS there is much more rows and I don't know what to do, can somebody help me?
I think that problem is with point 3)

My code:

```
Sub OLAP_Connect()
    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

    Dim rowCount As Long
    
    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
Dim intMaxCol As Integer
Dim intMaxRow As Integer


'1) connection
    
    Cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=MSOLAP; Data Source=CZSTRDWHSQL01;  Initial Catalog=CPI_SSAS;"

'2) Query SQL
        Row_1 = "[Company].[Company].[Company]"
        Row_2 = "[Account].[Account Code].[Account Code]"
        Row_3 = "[Account].[Account Full Name].[Account Full Name]"
        Col_1 = "[Measures].[Turnover Accounting Currency]"
    
    SQL = " select " & _
        " non empty (" & Col_1 & ") on Columns, " & _
        " non empty (" & Row_1 & ", " & Row_2 & ", " & Row_3 & ") on Rows " & _
        " from [cpi dwh]" & _
        " where ([Company].[Company Code]. & [P004],[Company].[Company CountryCode].&[POL],[Transaction Date].[Month Number].&[1],[Transaction Date].[Year].&[2022])"
       

'3) connection to OLAP and import date
    Cn.Open
    

        Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
        rs.ActiveConnection = Cn
        rs.Source = SQL
        rs.CursorType = ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenKeyset

 
        rs.Open SQL, Cn
               
        Range("A4").CopyFromRecordset rs
                
        rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing
'add name of columns to excel
    Cells(1, 1) = Row_1
    Cells(1, 2) = Row_2
    Cells(1, 3) = Row_3
    Cells(1, 4) = Col_1
End Sub
```

I made some changes in code (from forums) but all of them gives me same result only 1 row...

Comment: Welcome Tom! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow
https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: This looks as though it might help. https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/import-data-from-tabular-model-in-excel-using-a-dax-query/

Comment: How do you know the MDX query returns multiple rows? Have you executed it in SSMS to confirm?

Comment: User10186832 - thanks I know how to do it but it's not that what I want.
GregGalloway - yes I my MDX code is working in SQL Management server SSAS and I see correct table.
In my project I would like to create somethink like excel aplication for other users (which they don't know how to work on power query and other programs) to download correct tables. Tables must be depending on the attributes selected in excel

Comment: User10186832 - thanks I know how to do it but it's not that what I want.
GregGalloway - yes I my MDX code is working in SQL Management server SSAS also in power query but it lose some time.... 
The problem is that I am creating something like aplication in excel for other users who don't know how to use queries etc. My query SQL/MDX will be changed in VBA deppends of attributes used in excel for exceample: different months or companies allocated in list.
I don't wont to do it by power query becouse the CUBE is such a big. Currently we are useing cube by pivot tables but it takes lot of time

Comment: i find a problem, i need to paste: rs.MoveFirst before Range("A4").CopyFromRecordset rs. Now is working